# Good resourse for Ising Problem Model

Tags: quantum-information, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, quantum-computer, ising-model

I am student of mathematics, and I will wrote theoretical article about Ising problem in Adiabatic Computation. Do you have a good resource where it is good explaining? In my context I have information about operators and spaces where it's based.